# How to call a SoapServer from PHP

Tags: php, soap-client

So far I haven't been able to successfully pass the parameters into the request via the PHP SoapClient.

```
<?php

class MockSoapClient extends \SoapClient
{
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
        echo $request.PHP_EOL;

        return '';
    }
}

$client = new MockSoapClient(
    'http://www.saiasecure.com/webservice/shipment/soap.asmx?wsdl',
    [
        'trace' => 1,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    ]
);

$client->__soapCall(
    'GetByProNumber',
    [
        'parameters' => [
            'UserID' => 'username',
            'Password' => 'password',
            'TestMode' => 'Y',
            'ProNumber' => '123',
        ]
    ]
);
```

Running with: php test.php | xmllint -format -

Getting the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.SaiaSecure.com/WebService/Shipment">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetByProNumber/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Expecting output to contain some form of the parameters within the GetByProNumber element.

Version of PHP: 7.0.30 (Ubuntu 16.04)

There are "not a bug" reports that closely mimic the issue, but I'm not able to get insight into what to change to get this working. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33366

Anyone have any insights or tips?

Comment: Usually one does not need to extend `SoapClient`. Your code should be as simple as `$client = new SoapClient('http://www.saiasecure.com/webservice/shipment/soap.asmx?wsdl'); $client->GetByProNumber('username', 'password', 'Y', 123);`

Comment: I had extended the client to intercept the request, before sending broken messages to a service I don't own.

Comment: The code I posted still stands. This is how you use the SOAP client no matter if you extend it or not.

Comment: The code you posted still fails in the same way as the original question.  If you're code used the call: `$client->GetByProNumber(['request' => ['UserID' => 'username', 'Password' => 'password', 'TestMode' => 'Y', 'ProNumber' => '123']]);` it appears it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your wsdl, it seems the right parameters array should be like this:

```
[
    'parameters' => [
        'request' => [
            'UserID' => 'username',
            'Password' => 'password',
            'TestMode' => 'Y',
            'ProNumber' => '123',
        ]
    ]
]
```

then the output would be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.SaiaSecure.com/WebService/Shipment"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetByProNumber><ns1:request><ns1:UserID>username</ns1:UserID><ns1:Password>password</ns1:Password><ns1:TestMode>Y</ns1:TestMode><ns1:ProNumber>123</ns1:ProNumber></ns1:request></ns1:GetByProNumber></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```